# How to dismiss viewController in ios using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I have a viewController which contains only an imageview. I want to present it whenever there is a loading in the application like fetching data from a webservice. So I have created a function in my loaderViewController as

```
func showLoading(viewController:UIViewController) {
    viewController.presentViewController(LoadingViewController(), animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

This is working as expected, when I call this function when desired like below

```
var loader = LoadingViewController()
loader.showLoading(self)
```

It show me the viewController with image.

But Now  want to dismiss this viewController when desired but I am not able to do so, This is what I have tried so far, I created another function in my LoaderViewController as

```
func dismissLoader() {
    let load = LoadingViewController()
    load.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
        print("Dismissing Loader view Controller")
    }
}
```

But its not working and the viewController is not disappering from the screen.

Please guide me

Comment: Are YASLoadingViewController and  LoadingViewController  same??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have to create a new instance of your loader and call `dismissViewControllerAnimated(_:Bool)` on it.

Just call

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

on your viewController

So, your function will be

```
func dismissLoader() {

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
        print("Dismissing Loader view Controller")
    }
}
```

Comment: can you rewrite the dismissLoader function for me please ?

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 3 you can do following.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

do not make `let load = YASLoadingViewController()` everytime, you are creating different controller
Do it once and then use only `load` to dismiss or present

Comment: is this an answer ?

Comment: Your answers are often right, but if you will provide more wide explanation they will be really useful. I think askers often are not qualified enough for understand your short answers

Answer (score 1):

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has many flaws. The way you trying to achieve this is not a good practice. However ,If you want a quick fix, and just want to modify your existing method do this,

```
func dismissLoader() {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) 
    print("Dismissing Loader view Controller")
}
```

And when you're presenting a new `LoadingViewController` , keep a reference to it, so you can call above method.

Anyways, above code should work even without you holding a reference, since iOS delegate this method back to it's parent ViewController of it's hierarchy, if there's no presented ViewController available on the called   ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store a link for `LoadingViewController` in parent view controller:

```
var loader: LoadingViewController?

func showLoadingIn(viewController: UIViewController) {
   loader = LoadingViewController() // create new instance before presentation
   viewController.presentViewController(loader!, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func dismissLoader() {
    loader?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
        print("Dismissing Loader view Controller") 
    }
}
```